# Issue accessing Session state from user control

Tags: vb.net, session, .net-3.5

I am getting the following error when trying to pull from the Session state in the code behind of a user control.

**Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.**

Here is the config that I have in the  section

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
<pages enableSessionState="true"></pages>
<httpModules>
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

Here is the how I reference in on the user control itself. This is done in Page_Load

```
If Not Session("ADName") Is Nothing AndAlso Session("ADName").length > 0 Then
'Do Stuff
End If
```

And my control declaration

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UCHeader.ascx.vb" Inherits="PO.Web.UCHeader"
    TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>
```

What would be causing this issue. I am trying to build locally and get this issue, so it is not related to IIS at all. I am migrating this app from 2.0 to 3.5 and started getting the error at that time. Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks.

Comment: So `EnableSessionState` is not set to `false` in the [page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx)?

Comment: Where do you see that? Plus there is no EnableSessionState property in the page directive of a UserControl, only host pages.

Comment: I don't see it, that's why i'm _asking_. But what i've meant is that you've shown the web.config, but the page would override this setting if `EnableSessionState` is set.

Comment: Sorry about that snarky. There is nothing in the declaration. Adding the property does nothing. Is there something else that needs to be done for UserControls?

Comment: You may have the problem by not using `Session.Item("ADName")` instead of `Session("ADName")`

Comment: Tried Session.Item and get the same error

Comment: Does the host page from where you use the UserControl have EnableSessionState set to true?